# Definition of $f$ approaches limit algebraically

Tags: definition

I read a formulation like:

"The function $f(x)$ approaches its limit value of $2$ algebraically."

So I'm wondering what's the mathematical equivalant definition of "approching a limit algebraically". In other words, what do I have to show to prove that statement?

Comment: I'm assuming it must mean that your function is a sum/difference/product/quotient. See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Properties

Comment: Could you give us some context?

Comment: Unfortunately not so much,only so far as I can say, that there are functions $f_n$ defined on some compact intterval $[0,n]$ and the function $f$ should be defined as the limit $f:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n$ and every $f_n$ satisfies $f_n(n)=2$. So obviously it makes sense that $f$ reaches the value $2$ for $s\rightarrow\infty$. Only "algebraically" confuses me.

Comment: Maybe there could be a distinction in "algebraically" and "exponentially"? Is there a noticeable difference?